# Package installation not working in R

Tags: r, package

**Nevermind, fixed it.  Will write up comment explaining fix tn.**

I am trying to install the geometric morphometrics package in R, but whenever I try to install it, I get the following error message:

```
> install.packages("geomorph")

There is a binary version available but the source version is later: binary source needs_compilation geomorph  3.0.5  3.0.6             FALSE

installing the source package ‘geomorph’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/geomorph_3.0.6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 545863 bytes (533 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 533 KB

Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
unknown timezone 'default/America/Toronto'
* installing *source* package ‘geomorph’ ...
** package ‘geomorph’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
there is no package called ‘mvtnorm’
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘geomorph’
* removing      ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/geomorph’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘geomorph’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
      ‘/private/var/folders/4p/m9yg9rg94v13j49zxnp9kzzh0000gn/T/RtmpCBCHAn/downloaded_packages’
```

I'm using RStudio but I tried it in just R, I've updated to the latest MacOS HighSierra, I have tried restarting the applications, I've installed and restarted XQuartz, and so far nothing has worked.

I'm running R on an early 2015 MacBook Air, I'm fresh out of ideas.  Any suggestions are welcome.

**EDIT:**

Trying to install mvtnorm also failed, producing the following:

```
> install.packages("mvtnorm")

There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
binary source needs_compilation
mvtnorm  1.0-6  1.0-7              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?
y/n: y
installing the source package ‘mvtnorm’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/mvtnorm_1.0-7.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 159381 bytes (155 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 155 KB

* installing *source* package ‘mvtnorm’ ...
** package ‘mvtnorm’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -   I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -    Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c C_FORTRAN_interface.c -o C_FORTRAN_interface.o
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -    I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -    Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c miwa.c -o miwa.o
gfortran-4.8   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c mvt.f -o mvt.o
make: gfortran-4.8: No such file or directory
make: *** [mvt.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mvtnorm’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/mvtnorm’
* restoring previous  ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/mvtnorm’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘mvtnorm’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/4p/m9yg9rg94v13j49zxnp9kzzh0000gn/T/RtmpCBCHAn/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: Looks like it depends on "mvtnorm" but that's not installed. Try running `install.packages("mvtnorm")` first.

Comment: Also, the timezone is wrong. What does `Sys.getenv("TZ")` return? Perhaps you could try `Sys.setenv(TZ="America/Toronto")` first then retry installation (of `mvtnorm` and `geomorph`).

Comment: Trying to install mvtnorm produces a different error, I will edit it into my main comment.

Comment: I used the suggested time command but it had no effect.

Comment: It doesn't seem like your system is set up to compile source packages. When it asks if you want to install from source, say "no" (n).

Comment: Tried that as well previously, didn't work, but I will get the code.

Comment: I think you want to look [here](https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/rcpp-rcpparmadillo-and-os-x-mavericks--lgfortran-and--lquadmath-error/) ...

Comment: In what way did it fail when you said "no" ?

Comment: Sorry, fixed.  I was mistaken there was no problem when I inputted no, it just gave another error when I tried to install geomorph because there were other problems as well and I didn't notice the error message had changed.  Thanks anyways!